# How to configure case sensitive database identifier in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

How to configure case sensitive database identifier in mysql. so that database 'testDatabase' and 'TestDatabase' will not be considered same.

Comment: [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL online documentation provides information about identifier case sensitivity in section 9.2.2.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html
If you are running MySQL on Windows or Mac (unless using Mac with UFS file system) both databases will be treated the same.
If stored on Unix based systems which have case sensitive file systems you can store them as separate data base's.